# Preventing XSS attacks to dynamically created DOM webpages and dynamically generated javascript event handlers

Tags: asp.net, security

I have read the following article:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355989.aspx

Now this article allows me to understand XSS vulnerability defense to a webpage that is statically made up of asp and html controls built on a webpage as in true markup layout fashion. I now understand that that control input should use not only server side in validation but input should validate length, range, format and type. The question I have is that I am trying to sanitize a website where the page layout controls are build on to the DOM object dynamically when the page loads. For example on the page load event methods add controls to the document object one at a time in the method that builds the entire webpage during that calling method. Also, control event handling is done by methods that send concatenated JavaScript strings, during page load,  as output to the page that handle page control events. I guess my question is, how do I use asp.net validation controls, regex checking, etc. functionally when everything is built, the DOM and JavaScript event handling on the loading of the webpage?

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid the MS article has misled you. It represents a misguided, discredited approach to handling injection issues. (ASP.NET Request Validation in particular is an unreliable waste of your time.)

Input validation is valuable for ensuring incoming data conform to expected business rules and doesn't contain confusing characters like control characters, but it is not a reliable means of preventing HTML or JS injection issues leading to cross-site-scripting.

The way to prevent injection issues is, whenever you are inserting text into a wider context, to encode the text to fit that context. So, when you're templating a string into HTML, HTML-escape it; when you're putting a parameter into a URL, URL-escape it; when you're writing a string into a `<script>` block, JS-escape it, and so on.

In ASP.NET templates that means using the `<%: ... %>` construct to put content in a page instead of `<%= ... %>`, as this HTML-escapes automatically. (In Razor, the `@{...}` construct also automatically escapes.)

At the client side you have to look at the code that is being used to create the new DOM elements. In general the classic bad pattern to look out for is creating markup with strings inserted into it, like:

```
element.innerHTML = '<div>Hello, '+name+'</div>';
```

the quick fix here is to write a function to do the HTML-escaping on the client side, eg:

```
function escapeHTML(s) {
    return s.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/"/g, '&quot;').replace(/'/g, '&#039;');
}

element.innerHTML = '<div>Hello, '+escapeHTML(name)+'</div>';
```

It's usually better to avoid this kind of DOM-XSS problem by writing data directly to DOM properties, so you don't need to do any escaping:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.textContent = 'Hello, '+name;
element.appendChild(div);
```

(Similarly if using jQuery, prefer setting `text()` and `attr()` to `html()`.)

Comment: OK. I see that my understanding of XSS was wrong. Now, back to my initial question. In the past the ASP controls and mark-up was the typical static layout embedded into the HTML when the page was designed. Now, following your example what is the best was to sanitize webpages that have the layout created dynamically at runtime? In my case asp controls and JavaScript handling the control events are created and inserted into the DOM during the page load event. See the example here:

Comment: It's not possible, in the general case, to address injection problems by means of “sanitisation” of input separate to the code that builds injected strings. I can't see any link to an example, but if you are creating controls at the server side with markup in them, any text you put into that markup needs to be `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode`d.

Comment: If you're using the original ASP.NET Web Controls, the bad news is that they're completely inconsistent about whether they HTML-escape for you or not. Even a property called `Text` might be text, markup, or either (switched on `LiteralMode`) depending on the control. This, not to put too fine a point on it, sucks. Background: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cisg/archive/2008/09/17/which-asp-net-controls-need-html-encoding.aspx